# MVVM without a binding framework on iOS

Tags: ios, mvvm

I'm planning to utilize MVVM for a new iOS Application that will be written in Swift. I know that MVVM works better with a binding framework like Reactive Cocoa but I'm a bit discourage to use a binding framework because of the learning curve and the complexity involved with it. Is it a bad idea to use MVVM but not use a binding framework ?. How would one manage this complexity ?

Comment: Without binding it's kind of hard to enforce the decoupling, since you'll have to write code that access view elements and I doubt inventing your own binding framework will have a lower learning curve than using an already existing binding framework ;)

Comment: You can but like Tseng said, you'll just end up creating bindings.  Some way for the view to know when it needs to update and a way for the view to update view model properties.

Comment: Take a look here https://www.mobiledefense.com/blog/2016/02/07/pure-swift-mvvm/